# Cases of $A^2 = -I$. Why is there a contradiction when reusing this proof?

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

I had to prove that $\nexists ~A \in M_{3,3}(\mathbb R) : A^2 = - \mathbb I.$

I argued

$$\iff A=-A^{-1}$$
$$\iff \det( A)=\det(-A^{-1})$$
$$\iff \det( A)=(-1)^n\det A^{-1}$$
$$\iff \det (A) + \det (A^{-1})=0 ~~~\text{since n=3}$$

But as $ ~\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=1$, the signs of the determinants of A and its inverse have to be equal, and since $\mathbb O^2=\mathbb O$, $\det(A)$ and $\det(A^{-1})$ are either both positive or both negative $\rightarrow$ contradiction.

However, if I replace $n$ in the 3<sup>rd</sup> line with $2$, it is (seemingly) possible to deduce the equivalent statement $A=A^{-1}$ and furthermore $A^2=\mathbb I$, which would contradict where I took off (but there exist such matrices, take 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$, for example).

Where is $\iff$ not appropriate?

Comment: How can you deduce $A = A^{-1}?$ Note that $\det A = \det A^{-1}$ does not imply $ A = A^{-1}$. Also for a simpler proof of your original theorem: just take the determinant directly of $A^2 = -I\to (\det A)^2 = -1$.

Answer (score 2):

The second one: It may happen that $|A| = |B|$ and $A \neq B$.

Comment: Does the proof still work if I replace it with $\implies$?

Comment: Yes. That's what should be done.